# AppDomain isolation issue

Tags: c#, assemblies, appdomain

I've architected a back-end in such a way that the business logic is placed in dlls that are loaded at run-time. Using ShadowCopyFiles = true, and filesystem monitoring, I am able to modify business logic without restarting the host process.

So far so good...

Let's call the host appdomain A, and one of the children B.

Unfortunately, if I make changes in an assembly C, which is referenced by B but not A, these changes are not reflected when B is reloaded. I assume it is because A loads C itself. What steps do I have to take to prevent A from loading C?

This is the code used by A to load B:

```
        AppDomainSetup appDomainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
        appDomainSetup.CachePath = ServiceDLLPath + @"\Shadow";
        appDomainSetup.ShadowCopyFiles = "true";

        ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain(assemblyName, null, appDomainSetup);
        ad.InitializeLifetimeService();
        try
        {
            service = (IService)ad.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(assemblyName, 
                                  "AppName.Services." + typeName);
            service.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogManager.Log("AppDomain load failed: " + e.Message);
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `A` references `C` and `A` is the 'host', you cannot reload `C` without stopping and restarting the process.

One possibility would be to make an extremely thin shim AppDomain that bootstraps the `A` AppDomain (and can restart it), but retsrating the process would probably be about the same performance profile.

The other (seemingly saner) approach would be to make `A` and it's dependencies independent of those used by `C`, and for the overlapping assemblies just make them stable enough that you don't need to change them very often.

Comment: Thanks for your response Chris. A does not explicitly reference C. But A references B, which references C. That should be OK, no?

Comment: When I build A, I can see that it makes a local copy of C, despite the fact that it's not directly referenced, so I guess there is some kind of recursive search of assemblies.

Comment: References are implicitly recursive, yes.  If `A` references `B`, and `B` references `C`, then loading `A` will load `C`.

Comment: That brings us back to the problem. How to change C without restarting A?

Comment: Did you read my answer?  It is not possible to change a loaded assembly or to reload an individual assembly other than unloading the whole appdomain and starting a new one.  You need to figure out how to architect your application such that you don't need to change `C` very often, or so that `A` does not reference it (directly or indirectly).

Comment: I realize you can't unload individual assemblies and I did read your answer. I am unloading the entire B appdomain. I just find it weird that I can isolate A from B (by hosting in an appdomain and destroying it whenever I want to) but not C, which is one step further away.

Comment: That's because types leak across app domains.  If an assembly is loaded in Appdomain `A` and Appdomain `B` needs that assembly, it will not be reloaded.  It will use the one that was loaded in AppDomain `A`.

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved it by creating an 'interface' assembly.

So if this assembly is called X, the chain is now:

A -> X <- B -> C

(originally: A -> B -> C)

I can now make changes in either B or C, which get reflected when appDomain B is destroyed and restarted by A.

**EDIT**, as requested by Tim, some more details.

The code in appdomain A has not changed, you can see it my question. The only thing that needed attention was the location of the IService type definition:

```
 service = (IService)ad.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(assemblyName, 
                              "AppName.Services." + typeName);
```

Once IService was moved to a purpose built assembly, I was able to remove references in both B and A that in some way ended up connecting A to C. Basically everything Chris said is correct, it's just that it's not always clear what the path is.

Comment: Care to show us a snippet of how you did it? Atleast your post will then be a valuable answer and probably also recieve credits for it. :-)

Comment: Not much code to show regarding change, see my updated answer. I can share the monitoring/restarting code if you are interested. Will most likely be accepting Chris' answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the answers and comments, it sounds like you are better off wrapping the business logic into WCF services. You can use net pipe to minimise overhead for running on the same pc. You should also look at MEF for building application extensibility. Unfortunately MEF is also not designed to allow you to unload and replace the plugin on the fly without restarting the host application

Comment: If I were to do this again, I would go down that route. Seems like loading logic dynamically using Appdomains is not worth the trouble. I'm not even sure under what circumstances this appdomain approach outperforms "one process per service + WCF".